# System requirements for solr server?

Tags: solr

What is the minimum system requirements for the solr server to run & perform in better way ?

For example,

1. RAM size
2. Disk space & other details...

In my case, solr handles around 1GB of indexed data. Can you please specify the hardware/system requirements for this one to handle in better way...

Comment: There is no stated minimum. Bigger is better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes am getting the point. In my case, solr working fine in my system(4GB RAM) where as the environment given to deploy the solr is about 1GB RAM. In the 1GB environment, am getting the response for the search is little slow.

Comment: Okay, so clearly you need to increase the deployed environment's available system resources. Why is there even a question here?

Comment: Thanks again Matt Ball. Yes ofcourse. I thought it will be better to know if there is any specification related to hardware requirements for solr deployment.

Comment: I used to run it on a 512 MB VPS (Linode) and a few 1000 docs never took it outside its preallocated minimum (40mb). Please check your memory usage: I guess the processor may be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to this question, as stated in this article - S[izing Hardware in the Abstract: Why We Don't Have a Definitive Answer.](https://lucidworks.com/post/sizing-hardware-in-the-abstract-why-we-dont-have-a-definitive-answer/) It all depends on your data, how your index is structured, etc.

Here are some additional resources that may assist you:

- [Estimating Memory and Storage for Lucene/Solr](https://lucidworks.com/post/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/)
- [Lucene/Solr Size Estimating Spreadsheet](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_2_0/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls) (from the previous article)

A good case in point is your comment that your index is performing well on a 4GB machine, but not on a 1GB machine.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It helped me a lot to understand.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead, but it was probably this: https://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/

Comment: I corrected the links. Thanks Kimberly W for pointing out these were dead.

Comment: none of the link is working :(

Comment: Fixed the links to the Lucidworks blog pages.