# Hoster requirements for running Solr

Tags: solr, hosting, requirements

I am planning to add a full-text search engine for searching a MySQL database to a website. Most recommendations on a nice, user-friendly implementation I found, mentioned the use of Apache Solr.

Keeping this in mind I started searching for the requirements for a hoster to use Solr but I didn't find any useful information expect for "it should support java". So I picked a random host that states it has Java JRE installed (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/What_We_Support) and asked if they supported Solr. Unfortunately, the answer was "no".

So, what would I need to be looking for? Do I need a dedicated server, a VPN, or are there shared hosting solutions where it is possible to run Solr?

What are the system requirements?

I hope there is someone out there, who knows a bit about this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate – this should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703338/system-requirements-for-solr-server

Comment: Also check out this book - ISBN-13: 978-8192784502 (Mastering Apache Solr, by Nayrolles). It contains deployment options and is recommended on the official SolR website.

Comment: First, thanks for the info! But I already found the topic you linked. My question is rather on the software side. How can I determine if I would be able to use Solr on server wrt software requirements. What restrictions prevent running it, or on the other hand, what needs to be available.

Comment: But for the software side, you can refer to the given book as well, plus you can create a local setup on your machine and take notes what you installed. And there is documentation on the web, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr , https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall

Comment: Okay, I'll have to look where I can rent or buy the book. Anyway, am I right in that the most important thing to look for, is the availability of a JRE which allows running servlet containers (Jetty, Tomcat, ..)? And since I'm using PHP, I would need the PHP [Solr extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) and therefore pecl support for installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solr requirements can be found here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall

So an installed JRE is needed, but also an servlet container, which also needs an JRE.

If I would be in your situation, I would rent an virtual server.
An other option is an hosting service, specialized for solr hosting: search the web for "apache solr hosting". There are offers for free or payed offers also.

Comment: Thank you, Bndr! Then, I'll probably look for a virtual server!

Answer (score 0):

I've been running two drupal websites + apache solr on an ssd vps from [rosehosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/) utilizing 2 cpu cores and 1gb ram. I wasn't able to setup apache solr and java myself so that's why I rented a managed vps service.

If you're not that technical I suggest you add managed to the keywords mentioned by @The Bndr and make sure you check with your host that they will support apache solr and java on your vps